# GCP-The App Engine APIs are not available, with py 3

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to consume Admin SDK API from App Engine using a service account with domain wide delegation that allows it to impersonate an admin.

I found several guides to do so but no one works as I expect.

The code below are deployed into App Engine Standard.

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from google.auth import app_engine
import google.auth


try:
    import googleclouddebugger
    googleclouddebugger.enable()
except ImportError:
    pass

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    credentials, project = google.auth.default()

    appIdentity = app_engine.app_identity

    credentials = app_engine.Credentials(scopes=SCOPES)

    ret = "Expired:{}".format(credentials.expired)
    ret += "\nvalid:{}".format(credentials.valid)
    return 'Hello World!\n'+ret


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python37
```

The code `credentials = app_engine.Credentials(scopes=SCOPES)` will cause 500 error message to the application because of the `app_engine.app_identity` is always `none`.

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/srv/main.py", line 52, in hello
    credentials = app_engine.Credentials(scopes=SCOPES)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/app_engine.py", line 107, in __init__
    'The App Engine APIs are not available.')
OSError: The App Engine APIs are not available."
```

As you can see the error report `The App Engine APIs are not available` but there is no API with the same name into the GCP project.

Below all the APIs that i enable into the project trying to achieve what it is asking for. Of course, the error still appear.

[image: GCP Project Enabled APIs]

This is a test environment, if anyone needs to access just ask, i will happy to give you viewer permission on the GCP Project

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the python37 runtime (the 2nd generation standard environment) which isn't compatible with the app engine API (only the python27/1st generation one is). From [Understanding differences between the Python 2 and Python 3 environments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#env):

> Proprietary App Engine APIs are not available in Python 3. This
>   section lists recommended replacements.

The `from google.auth import app_engine` won't actually be usable since they're based on the [App Identity API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/), one of those proprietary ones.

For authentication in the python37 runtime follow the [Granting your app access to Cloud services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/access-control#apps) section. Basically unlike the App Identity API in which you call `Credentials()` once and then use the app identity to access services, in python37 you authenticate for each service you need using the respective service API `Client()` call (or equivalent):

> ```
> # If you don't specify credentials when constructing the client, the
> # client library will look for credentials in the environment.
> storage_client = storage.Client()
> ```

If the service account you want to use is not the app's default service account then you need to specify it:

> You can override this default flow by doing any of the following:
>
> - Set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. If this variable is set, Cloud services use the credentials specified by
>     the variable instead of the default service account.
> - Specify credentials when you instantiate the `Client` object for a Cloud service. For example, if your app is calling a Cloud service in
>     a different project, you may need to [pass credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_the_path_to_the_service_account_key_in_code).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Have you some suggestion if after that i need to use the domain wide delegation starting from the appengine service account?
I search several times but it seems that the only way is to use a service account json key to auth as SA and then impersonate another account. Do you know some way to do that starting from che .Client() method?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I didn't play in the area. But I stumbled over [this](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.impersonated_credentials.html), it *sounds* potentially related.